# generalized modeling and state space models?

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, control-theory

I know some basic information about GM (Generalized state-space modeling) and state space. I read this book on google page 121 about it [Book](http://wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~poldermanjw/onderwijs/DISC/mathmod/book.pdf). I get one conclusion: state space modelling is specific case of GM.

How we can show that this conclusion is hold?

Comment: here you can [read all about GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Motors) ... if you would like to [become a GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandmaster_(chess)#Current_regulations) the conditions are quite difficult to meet

Comment: @terrace sorry now is it fix?